# Adding parameters to a .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect a url but I can't seem to make it work for some reason. I'm trying to redirect **my.domain.com/rss/abc/** to **my.domain.com/rss/abc/?type=555**

I've put this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirects rss
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/rss/abc/?$ /rss/abc/?type=555 [R=301,L]
```

Any pointers ? This is on a old TYPO3 site. Anyway it could hijack the request before doing the redirect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only recommend to use some kind of online htaccess rewrite rule checker, for example https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ (not the only one, and no real preferance or recommendation about others).

Your rewrite rule is wrong, it should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirects rss
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^rss/abc/?$ /rss/abc/?type=555 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'm crazy. I already tried without the leading slash and it wasn't working. That's why I then tested with the / at the begin (tha's where my copy/paste comes from). Anyway I moved my redirect up in the .htaccess and retried without the slash and it worked. 


It's either i didn't test properly the first time or some other redirection was interfering. Anyway thank you very much !! :D